# Internet speed in Nha Trang Vietnam?

Tags: internet, vietnam

Has anyone been to **Nha Trang** city in **Vietnam**? What is the internet speed there? Wi-fi and mobile internet.

Comment: In general Internet Cafes in Vietnam are faster and cheaper than in Cambodia or Laos. I don't remember any specific places in Nha Trang, but you should be able to find a place with decent connectivity. 

As for Wi-fi and mobile internet, I don't know because I don't bring my own devices when I travel.

Comment: Most (if not all) hotels (except high-star-rating hotels) and cafes in Vietnam have free wifi for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was there last year, and I remember connecting to internet in a café. The internet was really ok; nothing to complain about.

Moreover, in general in Vietnam the internet connection is good. Some places censor Facebook though

Comment: Generally, I found that Facebook was blocked and people needed to use a VPN to circumvent the block.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on where you stay and visit. In general it is okie and fast in some internet cafe. Mobile internet connection must be faster now since 3G is more popular in VN.